# Why are components not updating their content after a call to setState()?

Tags: reactjs, setstate, react-component

I am trying to show user-specific data in a simple page using React. However, even after being able to fetch the user data using `axios` for HTTP requests and calling `setState()` to update the state of the root component, the data shown in the page is still not changing.

Here is the code for the main component:

```js
    class UserPage extends React.Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super (props)

        this.state = {userId: null, username: null, clientId: null, jobs: null}
    }

    componentDidMount () {
        getSessionUserData ()
        .then (res => {
            this.setState({userId: res.data.id, username: res.data.username, clientId: res.data.client_id})
        })
    }

    render () {
        console.log ("rendering", this.state)
        return (
            <div id="user-page">
                <PageHeader text={"Welcome, " + this.state.username} id="user-page-header"/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

As you can see, `PageHeader` takes data from the main component's state. Here is the code for the `PageHeader` component:

```js
export class PageHeader extends React.Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {text: props.text}
    }

    render () {
        console.log ("rendering header with text: ", this.props.text)
        return (
            <h1 id={this.props.id}>{this.state.text}</h1>
        )
    }
}
```

I added the `console.log()` inside the `UserPage` component's `render()` method in order to check if it was being called after `setState()` and to make sure the state had been updated, and it turns out it is indeed being called, and the state is indeed being updated. Here is an image of what the console prints out whenever I reload the page:

[Image showing page and console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGKEb.png)

In the image you can see that the `render()` method is being called again after `setState()` and the state has the new user data. Also, I added console logs for the `PageHeader` component's `render()` method to check if for some reason it was not being re-rendered, but they are being printed and with the correct text, so I don't quite understand why the data in the page is not changing. Could you please help me figure out why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing to

```
<h1 id={this.props.id}>{this.state.text}</h1>
```

State which was set in the constructor. Constructor is called once with initial props. Since you set ID to component, it is not recreated (reused). And you print `this.props.text` but render `this.state.text`. So you either have to implement 'componentDidUpdate' to react on props changes and there update your state or just simply replace `<h1 id={this.props.id}>{this.state.text}</h1>` to `<h1 id={this.props.id}>{this.props.text}</h1>`

Comment: Thanks, this change solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you use this.props.text instead of the this.state.text in the h1 tag then it should work. The state in the PageHeader component is being set on the constructor, which will only happen on the component creation, it will not be re-set on the second render.

```
export class PageHeader extends React.Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {text: props.text}
    }

    render () {
        console.log ("rendering header with text: ", this.props.text)
        return (
            <h1 id={this.props.id}>{this.props.text}</h1>
        )
    }
}
```